# Arduino Motor Ramp

Tags: c, arduino

I need some help with my arduino ramp motor code.
I am making a remote control robot. The remote has one button.

If the button is high: The motor should gradually increase its speed using pwm (Starting with `pwm=0`).The time period from standstill speed to maximum speed should be 1 second. Once it has reached maximum speed it should maintain the maximum speed (`pwm=255`).
The moment the button is released the motor should gradually decrease from the current speed to a complete standstill.

So far I have managed to write the ramp up and maintain speed part of the code; the code doesn't include the button part.

```c
int motor;
int motorpwm=11;
int x=1;
int i;

void setup()
{

pinMode(11,OUTPUT);
Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() 
{

for(int i=0;i<256;i=i+x)
 {
analogWrite(motorpwm,i);
Serial.println(i);
if(i==255)
  {
x=0;
Serial.println("PWM is maximum");
  }
 }
}
```

Please include the complete code including the button control part of the code.

Comment: Have you tried something ? What is your button pin ?

Comment: I can add a button pin on pin 8.

Comment: Your global variable 'i' is never used. Your for loop never ends either. Have a look at the BlinkWithoutDelay example in the IDE or see this: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=223286.0 Then you can run the code checking the button independantly from the code controlling the motors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I **do not assure** you if this is **bug-free** but you can **try this** and post your restults here, so that **I can debug** it for you. Here you go:

```
int motor;
int motorpwm = 11;
int x = 1;
int i;
int pwmValue;
void setup()
{
  pinMode(11, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(2, INPUT); //Button connected to Vcc and pulled down using a 10k resistor. 
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  if (digitalRead(2)) //if button is pressed it will read High signal
  {
    if (pwmValue <= 255)
    {
      analogWrite(motorpwm, pwmValue++);
      Serial.print("Going Up with value: ");
      Serial.println(pwmValue);
    }
    else
    {
      Serial.println("PWM is maximum");
    }
  }

  else
  {
    if (motorpwm > 0)
    {
      analogWrite(motorpwm, pwmValue--);
      Serial.print("Going down with value: ");
      Serial.print(pwmValue);
    }
    else
    {
      Serial.println("PWM is minimum");
    }
  }
}
```

[image: This is how you will connect your switch to pin 2]